# XRDP uses llvmpipe instead of nvidia graphics

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, xrdp

I installed xrdp using `sudo apt install xrdp`  and fixed the color profile problem using

```
[Allow Colord all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

I can now connect to my machine using Windows rdp, but it looks very laggy.
For some reason a session made using xrdp uses llvmpipe instead of the expected `GeForce 840M/PCIe/SSE2` which I get when I'm not using remote desktop:

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)
```

It seems like xrdp is screwing this up.
I already look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1752938, but the only solution provided doesn't work anymore since I use a newer nvidia driver [nvidia-driver-440-server (proprietary, tested)].

I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04.5